# How to see the list of ip addresses in 'recent' module?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

How to see the full list of ip addresses in 'recent' module? I want to see current hitcounts to adjust my values accordingly so no valid users gets accidentally blocked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in the files below `/proc/net/xt_recent/` assuming a new kernel.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to figure out current hitcounts from this packets numbers?

Comment: First: Read the manual. Second: Seen the numbers? `oldest_pkt: 2` means "two". Got it?

Comment: There isn't a way to figure out hitcounts from that file; oldest_pkt tells you which position in the list the oldest packet is, because it is a ring buffer. If you want hit counts, try `iptables -vL` (key here being adding `-v` to the usual `iptables -L`), which should show you the success count for each rule in the first column ("pkts").

Comment: @Score_Under Wouldn't the number of entries in the ring buffer (which I suppose follows the `oldest_pkt` field) representing the current `hitcount`?

Comment: The nature of a ring buffer is that it will be overwritten regularly, and has a fixed maximum size